# What is the maximum size of file which can be uploaded using wp_remote_post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wp_remote_post method for uploading video files on amazon server.

I have tried to upload 1 MB file and get this response:

***Your POST request fields preceeding the upload file was too large.***

I am able to upload large file (up to 100MB) using cUrl in WordPress.

So, I want to know what is the maximum file size which can be uploaded by using wp_remote_post?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

wp_remote_post() depends on the server default set values.

You need to set the following values in php.ini

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 100M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 100M
```

Or you can do it via .htaccess file also

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 100M
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have upload_max_filesize =0 (for unlimited upload limit) and post_max_size = 1024M in php.ini file.

Comment: Do both same because both are using and considering as a post upload
 upload_max_filesize =1024M

Comment: I have updated php.ini and set upload_max_filesize =1024M. But got same error.